# Undefined local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I keep getting an `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in method_missing': undefined local variable or method id' for User(no database connection):Class (NameError)`

I can't figure out what part of my code is wrong. I making a pdf uploading website using paperclip and devise

Here is my pdf model

```
    Class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user 
    has_attached_file :attachment



@user.documents.each do |document|
    image_tag document.attachment.url 
end
```

My User Model

```
        class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

        has_many :documents    
end
```

My pages controller

```
   def new 
    @document = Document.new
end

def create
    @document = Document.new(document_params)
    @document.save
end

private
def document_params
    params.require(:document).permit(:attachment).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
end
```

My view

```
<%= form_for @document, html: { miltipart: true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `multipart`, not `miltipart`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this

```
 id | name | etc | etc | created_at | updated_at
```

from user model

Comment: I'm guessing this is just a representation of the model's attributes – not actual verbatim code.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help. I removed that and now I keep getting a `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` error for my view page First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
          
    `<%= form_for @document, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
  <% end %>`

Comment: have u set @document to Document.new in the controller.Also remove this user.documents.each do |document| image_tag document.attachment.url end from document model if its there